# Flash Local Shared Object storage security issue?

Tags: macos, security, permission, adobe-flash

I have encountered some strange behavior when navigating through the flash Local Shared Object folders on my computer running OS X version 10.11.5

The behavior is as follows:

1. Navigate to the base local shared object storage `cd ~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/`
2. Navigate through the shared object using the below path `cd \#SharedObjects/6MB4PXSB/skype.com/`
3. On this path is another folder named "#ui"

If I change the directory to the #ui folder it takes me back to home folder i.e. it is the equivalent of typing `cd ~`

Listing the contents of parent folder shows the following:

```
> ls -latr
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser  staff  102 Jun 17 12:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser  staff  102 Jun 17 12:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser  staff  102 Jun 17 12:07 #ui
```

I do not see any symbolic links from #ui to my home folder so I am not sure why this is happening.  I have tested this repeatedly and it consistently takes me to my home folder.

My questions are:

1. Is this a security issue?
2. Is it safe for me to do an `rm -rf #SharedObject` given the observed behavior?

Comment: I'd open Disk Utility and run First Aid against the drive before doing anything else. See if it finds any problems with the filesystem structures.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan thanks for the suggestion.  I have already tried that and it finds nothing wrong with the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is used by the shell to indicate a comment. So if you type

```
cd #ui
```

everything after the `#` is ignored and you basically just execute `cd`. To change into the directory, use one of

```
cd ./#ui
cd \#ui
```

instead.

The same applies if you want to remove it.

Comment: The cynic in me says that adobe used the `#` on purpose to try to make it difficult to delete the "Shared Object" aka cookies by stealth.  Is it just me?